# Error: Main Method exceeding bytes limit

Tags: java, main-method

I'm having an issue where I'm getting the error code:

```
Error: The code of method main(java.lang.String[]) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
```

while programming java.

I'm really quite new to java, and I don't really know what to do now.

---

I have looked at other possible solutions, but I don't really understand what they are trying to say. I don't use arrays, and my code completely consists of do whiles and if statements.. I'm that new to all this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit error in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207388/the-code-for-the-static-initializer-is-exceeding-the-65535-bytes-limit-error-in)

Comment: Refactor your `main` method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "The code of method .. is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257398/how-to-fix-the-code-of-method-is-exceeding-the-65535-bytes-limit)

Comment: i wouldn't likfe to maintain your code...

Comment: I don't understand how to solve it though

Comment: You're not helping us help you... Show us the code in your main method.

Comment: Your main method is too long. Write some other functions move the code from main into them and call them from main which will make your main shorter.

Comment: ^^ what does that mean? I'm taking the course in school, and all we've learned is that method?

Comment: If your instructors have taught you to write an entire program in one enormous method that has 65k characters in it, demand your tuition be reimbursed and find a different school.

Answer (score 0):

If your code looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Do way too much stuff . . .
    }
}
```

Make it more like this

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doSomeStuff();
        doMoreStuff();
    }

    public static void doSomeStuff() {
        // Do some stuff but not too much
    }

    public static void doMoreStuff() {
        // Do some more stuff but not too much
    }
}
```